# Confusion about how self.something works in classes

Tags: python

Why doesn't this code work?

```
class Triangle(object):
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3

    number_of_sides = 3
    def check_angles(self):
        sum_of_angles = angle1 + angle2 + angle3 # PLS LOOK AT THIS LINE
        if sum_of_angles == 180:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

but this does?

```
class Triangle(object):
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3

    number_of_sides = 3
    def check_angles(self):
        sum_of_angles = self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 # LOOK HERE AGAIN
        if sum_of_angles == 180:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

if self.angle1 = angle1, why can't I just use the shorter version?

Comment: That is just how it is: `angle1` is a variable whose scope is the constructor, while `self.angle1` is a property of `self`. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

So to explain this, consider the following. When you get to the function `Triangle.check_angles`, consider what is defined at that point. You have your `self` object, which has angle1, angle2 and angle3 defined (i.e. you have `self.angle1`, `self.angle2` and `self.angle3` defined).

However, `angle1` itself is not a known variable, as it is not passed into the function (like it is in the `self.__init__` function). Thus if you ask for `angle1`, it is not defined, and raises an error. Is that clear?